# Using Managed EWS API ResolveName to get contact's Azure object ID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ews-managed-api

I am successfully using ResolveName to get most of the contact information I need.
Below is the code I am using:

PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
NameResolutionCollection match = await mailClient.Service.ResolveName(customerEmail, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, itempropertyset);

I am querying against my Office365/Azure AD tenant.
One of the values I need is not being returned though.

I would like to get the user/contact's Object ID as shown in the Azure Portal - Azure Active Directory - Users - Basic Info screen.

Is that possible using EWS Managed API?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get Azure AD user's **`object ID`** using *EWS Managed API*. Alternatively, you can make use of ***Microsoft Graph API***.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got below results:***

I have Azure AD user named **`Sri`** in my tenant with below properties:

[image]

To get the Azure AD user's details via **Graph API**, I ran below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_principal_name
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get only **`object ID`** of an Azure AD user, you can include ***$select*** in the query like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_principal_name?$select=id
```

**Response:**

[image]

Before running the above queries, make sure to **grant consent** to required permissions like below:

***Go to Graph Explorer -> Modify permissions -> Click on Consent***

[image]

You will get **consent screen** and click on **`Accept`** like below:

[image]

After granting the consent, you can run the queries successfully.